# Convert Pcap file to text using python script

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-requests, pcap

I used the below code to convert a `pcap file` to `text file` with the given columns. The output text file. Code doesn't give any error and it gives output but it gives it empty without any data. can you help please to find the error

```
from scapy.all import *
data = "Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap"
a = rdpcap(data)
os.system("tshark  -T fields -e _ws.col.Info -e http -e frame.time -e  "
      "data.data -w Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap > Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.txt -c 1000")
os.system("tshark -r Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap -Y http -w Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap")
sessions = a.sessions()
i = 1
for session in sessions:
 http_payload = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

tshark -F k12text -r a.pcap -w a.txt.

"K12 text format" is a text packet capture format; it's what some Tektronix equipment can write out - in that sense, it's similar to writing out the raw hex data, plus some metadata. However, from a user-interface sense, it's more like "Save As..." in Wireshark, because it's a capture file format.
I guess this should work for you

Answer (score 0):

The two tshark commands you're running are:

```
tshark -T fields -e _ws.col.Info -e http -e frame.time -e data.data -w Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap > Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.txt -c 1000
```

That command will do a *live capture* from the default interface, write 1000 captured packets to a capture file named `Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap` (probably pcapng, not pcap, as pcapng has been Wireshark's default capture format for many years now), and write the Info column, the word "http" for HTTP packets and nothing for non-HTTP packets, the time stamp, and any otherwise not dissected data out to `Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.txt` as text.

```
tshark -r Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap -Y http -w Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap
```

That will read the `Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap` capture file and write out the HTTP packets in it to the *same* file.  *This* is not recommended, because if you're reading from a file and writing to the same file in a given TShark command, you will write to the file as you're reading from it.  This may or may not work.

If you want to extract the HTTP packets to a file, I'd suggest writing to a *different* file, e.g.:

```
tshark -r Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap -Y http -w Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit-http-packets.pcap
```

So your first command does a *live* capture, writes the packets to a pcapng file, and writes the fields in question to a text file, and your second command overwrites the capture file you wrote in the first command.

The first command should product text - are you saying that the `Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.txt` file is empty?